# Cell Pattern Value to Columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any way of converting below pattern into columns?

Image is attached for reference to understand better what is the input pattern and what will be output required.

[image: Pattern Value to Columns]

another picture

[image]

EDIT: I've added another screenshot

[image]

Thank you for supporting.

Comment: Hi @Qadeer,,, yoo mean to say,,, if cell has word Day the entire row/adjacent cell should be Blue,,, for Night should Green !!

Comment: @RajeshS No, if cell has this pattern e.g. DDDDxxxxxxxNNNN, then count D in pattern and write below as 4, 7x's so the count should be 7 then 4N's so down below that it should return 4. its not about coloring, its about count D's, X's and N's. I hope i'm clear now

Comment: your pattern doesn't match with OUTPUT,, plz be clear is quite confusing!!

Comment: @RajeshS  convert the pattern in Cell A1  into table form as below:
Pattern: (in Cell A1)  
ddddxxxxxxxnnnnxxxdddxnnnxxx
   
Output: (A2:B9)
   
Pattern Letter Count of Letter 
 d         4 
 x         7 
 n         4 
 x         3 
 d         3 
 x         1 
 n         3 
 x         3

Comment: @RajeshS any luck ?

Comment: OKay,, I got  soon I'll come with solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111954/discussion-between-rajesh-s-and-qadeer).

Comment: Hi，Why day is 4?

Comment: @Lee because there are 4 D's .. "dddd"

Comment: This can be easily done with Power Query, available in Excel 2010+.  But what if there are several rows of pattern?  What would you want for output?  (Show an example, please)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld, I've updated the question with an example ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatting that you show in your desired output precludes using Power Query (which turned out to be more complicated than I thought).

But here is a VBA routine that will produce what you show from your input.

To enter this Macro (Sub), <kbd>alt-F11</kbd> opens the Visual Basic Editor.
Ensure your project is highlighted in the Project Explorer window.
Then, from the top menu, select `Insert/Module` and
paste the code below into the window that opens.

To use this Macro (Sub), <kbd>alt-F8</kbd> opens the macro dialog box. Select the macro by name, and <kbd>RUN</kbd>.

The macro **assumes** that your table (as shown in your screenshot)

- starts in A1
- Column headers in row 1
- sequential numbers in column A starting in A2
- Patterns start in B2

The notes in the macro, along with reading the code, should explain the algorithm used. But ask if anything is not clear.

```
Option Explicit
Sub patternToColumns()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes As Variant
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, S As String, v As Variant
    Dim arrList As Object, x(1) As Variant
    Dim col As Collection
    
'read the source data into VBA array
Set wsSrc = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=2)
End With

'set results destination
Set wsRes = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 4) 'D1

Set arrList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
Set col = New Collection

'split string on change in character
'store each pair of character/count as an array within an ArrayList
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc)
    arrList.Clear
    S = vSrc(I, 2)
    
    x(0) = Mid(S, 1, 1)
    x(1) = 1
    
    For J = 2 To Len(S)
        Select Case J
            Case Is < Len(S)
                If Mid(S, J, 1) = x(0) Then
                    x(1) = x(1) + 1
                Else
                    arrList.Add x
                    x(0) = Mid(S, J, 1)
                    x(1) = 1
                End If
            Case Is = Len(S)
                If Right(S, 1) = x(0) Then
                    x(1) = x(1) + 1
                    arrList.Add x
                Else
                    arrList.Add x
                    x(0) = Right(S, 1)
                    x(1) = 1
                    arrList.Add x
                End If
        End Select
    Next J
    
    'each completed array list represents one row of pattern
    '   and 2 columns of output
    'each collection item = 1 column pair of output
    col.Add Item:=arrList.toarray, Key:=CStr(I)
Next I

'dim results array
I = 0
For Each v In col
    I = IIf(I > UBound(v), I, UBound(v))
Next v

ReDim vRes(0 To I + 1, 1 To col.Count * 2)

'Populate the array

'headers
For J = 1 To UBound(vRes, 2) Step 2
    vRes(0, J) = J / 2 + 0.5
Next J

J = -1

For Each v In col
    J = J + 2
    I = 0
    For K = 0 To UBound(v)
        I = I + 1
        vRes(I, J) = v(K)(0)
        vRes(I, J + 1) = v(K)(1)
    Next K
Next v


'write to worksheet and format
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .CurrentRegion.Clear
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    
    .Replace "d", "day"
    .Replace "n", "night"
    .Replace "x", "off"
    
    With .Rows(1)
        For J = 1 To .Cells.Count Step 2
            Range(.Cells(J), .Cells(J + 1)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenterAcrossSelection
        Next J
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Style = "Output" 'may need to be more specific with non-English Excel
    
    Dim C As Range
    For Each C In rRes
        With C
            If .Value = "off" Then
                .Font.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)
                .Offset(0, 1).Font.Color = RGB(165, 165, 165)
            End If
        End With
    Next C
End With
    
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: worked as intended,

Answer (score 1):

I am sure there is a more elegant (simpler, say) solution, but the following works. It requires a table for looking up what to output for each letter in the string (so if a "d" is found, it returns "day" and so on) which the formula for first column of the output expects in A1:B3. Other than being somewhat brute force, one thing I did not see a way to correct in the time I had is that the output table's `Spill` functionality outputs both have a blank cell at their bottoms that is "surplus to needs"... but they DO work so:

1. First, the formula for the first column:

```
=TRANSPOSE(XLOOKUP(MID(D1,UNIQUE(IF(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),1,1),1)=MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1),1),1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1)),TRUE),1),A1:A3,B1:B3,"",0))
```

and then

2. Second, the formula for the second column:

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(INDEX(UNIQUE(IF(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),1,1),1)=MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1),1),1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1)),TRUE),,SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(UNIQUE(IF(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),1,1),1)=MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1),1),1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1)),TRUE)),2,1))-INDEX(UNIQUE(IF(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),1,1),1)=MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1),1),1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1)),TRUE),,SEQUENCE(1,COUNT(UNIQUE(IF(MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),1,1),1)=MID(D1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1),1),1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(D1),2,1)),TRUE)),1,1))),"")
```

and done.

I am sure that, if nothing else, the `TRANSPOSE()` functions can be done away with with cleverer use of `SEQUENCE()`, but I'm out of time.

The key trick in the second one is the use of `SEQUENCE()` starting with 2 subtracting `SEQUENCE()` starting at 1, and then doing a similar thing with `INDEX()` to use the positions to tell how many of whichever letter to report at each place in the output table.

Finally, the two column formulas are completely independent of each other's results. So edits to improve either will not ruin the other. And the second one is really just a few building block elements, not anything complex. Just obnoxious looking.

Comment: Hey @Jeorge ,, add some screen shot to justify the command you have applied so far,, will attract readers & you may get UP votes also.

Comment: was just going to ask is sequence is in excel 2010.  Which the question was tag with in addition to 2016.  If not I would Just start the answer with `2016 Solution` or something to that effect.

Comment: @Forwarded, i didn't find Sequence in excel 2010. but I'm using Microsoft Office ProPlus please do start your answer. i'm wating ….

Comment: @Qadeer I do not know how to do it in 2010, I just know some commands are not available to all the tags you listed, so I was pointing out that it would be prudent to state that the solution will only work for version XXXX and later.

Comment: @Jeorje, the blank surplus cells at the bottom of the solution you provided, is there any way to solve it ?